# Can not execute java program using java processBuilder

Tags: java, compilation, processbuilder

I have written a code that will compile and execute other program like C++, C or Java. Compile and execute C++ file has been successfully implemented. My written program can compile java program(This is how I create ProcessBuilder for compilation `processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("javac", fileName);`). But the problem is about java code execution. I have create processBuilder class like

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", fileName);
```

where the `fileName` is which .class file will be execute. Then I have set the working directory, inputfile path, and outputFilePath. But the `exit code` is non-zero, that is 1.In my case that is `RUN_TIME_ERROR` Bellow I have provided the execution method that I have wrote.

```
public CompileStatus execute(ProcessBuilder processBuilder, String fileLocation,
                             String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath,
                             long timeInMillis) {

    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    processBuilder.directory(new File(fileLocation));
    processBuilder.redirectInput(new File(inputFilePath));
    processBuilder.redirectOutput(new File(outputFilePath));

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        if (!process.waitFor(timeInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            return CompileStatus.TIME_LIMIT_EXIT;
        int exitCode = process.exitValue();
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            logger.info("Exit code {}", exitCode);
            return CompileStatus.RUN_TIME_ERROR;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("{}", e);
        return CompileStatus.EXECUTION_ERROR;
    }

    return CompileStatus.EXECUTION_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am trying to execute a very simple program .

```
public class C {
  public static final void main(String... args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);
 }

}
```

What am I missing in here ?

**======UPDATE======**

`inputFilePath` contain text file path that will be the input for the java program `C`. and `outputFilePath` contain a text file path will contain the output of the program `C` .

If I put 1 in the file that is indicated by `inputFilePath` then the output of the program `C` will stored in the file that is indicated by `outputFilePath`. The file should be contain 1. But at this time there is nothing in the file that is indicated by `outputFilePath` because there is an error at execution. I have checked the error inputstream  but there is nothing. But the exit code is the program `C` is 1.

I have put the log for more convenience.

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.controller.CompileRestController - userName loti, srcType java, srcFile /home/seal/test/C.java, inputFile /home/seal/test/in1.txt, outputFile Test
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - Code compilation started...
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - file location, /home/seal/test
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.CompileImpl - COMPILE_SUCCESS
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.ProcessBuilderFactory - Language java
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.ProcessBuilderFactory - File name C
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - Execution started
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - file location, /home/seal/test
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - input file path, /home/seal/test/in1.txt
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - output file path /home/seal/test/out.txt
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.engine.CompilerImpl - Exit code 1
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.broj.service.CompileImpl - Execution status RUN_TIME_ERROR
```

`ProcessBuilder` factory class.

```
public class ProcessBuilderFactory {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessBuilderFactory.class);

public static ProcessBuilder getProcessBuilderForCompile(String language, String fileName, String targetFileName) {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = null;
    if (Language.CPP.equalsIgnoreCase(language))
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("g++", fileName, "-o", targetFileName);//not support c++11 so far
    else if (Language.JAVA.equalsIgnoreCase(language))
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("javac", fileName);

    return processBuilder;
}

public static ProcessBuilder getProcessBuilderForExecution(String language, String fileName) {
    logger.info("Language {}", language);
    logger.info("File name {}", fileName);
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = null;
    if (Language.CPP.equalsIgnoreCase(language))
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./" + fileName);
    else if (Language.JAVA.equalsIgnoreCase(language))
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", fileName);

    return processBuilder;
}
}
```

**======Update======**

the content of the output file

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C
```

Comment: What's in your output file? Maybe keep your stdout and stderr separate to make them easier to separate.

Comment: @AndyTurner output file will contain the output of that target java program. In here that is output of C java program. I have checked the output of the error stream . but I have found nothing. Only the exit code is 1.

Comment: Have you tried manually executing the compiled java program?

Comment: Please include the contents of your output file in your question.  Without that, it’s hard to provide you with anything other than wild guesses.

Comment: @VGR I have added the content of the output file in the question. please take a look.

Comment: Have you verified that a file named `C.class` is present in the directory you specified?

Comment: @VGR I have checked . C.class is in the `/home/seal/test` directory. I have update my log output. `/home/seal/test` directory is set for both compilation and execution in a processBuilder. I have also added the factory class for `processBuilder`.

Comment: Does C.java contain a `package` statement?

Comment: @VGR No package statement . I have found the solution . That is `java -cp . C`. this is working.  But not understand what is `-cp .` means ? Could you elaborate ?

Comment: It tells Java to look for your class in the current directory (`.` is a shorthand for the current directory).  It shouldn’t be needed unless you’re using a many-years-old version of Java.

Comment: @VGR I am using java 8. What do you mean by `current directory` ? Those files (which will be compiled/execute) and the project is not in same directory. Files are in `/home/seal/test` and project is in `/home/seal/IdeaProjects/compile_engine`.